# Why aren't contacts working in SpriteView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm trying to get to know when two sprites contact each other but I'm not being able to get it to work.

The code below reproduces the problem. I expected the contact delegate methods to fire when I tap the red square and the yellow square reaches it. However, nothing happens. The code seems like a lot but is actually quite simple. I've added comments to make it easier to read:

```swift
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    private var node: SKSpriteNode!
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        // Set contact delegate to this class
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        // Have the Game Scene be the same size as the View
        size = view.frame.size

        // Create a yellow square with a volume based physics body that isn't dynamic
        node = SKSpriteNode(color: .yellow, size: CGSizeMake(50, 50))
        node.position = CGPointMake(100, 100)
        node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSizeMake(50, 50))
        node.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false

        // Set it's contact bit mask to any value (default category bitmask of 
        // SKSpriteNode is 0xFFFFFFFF so any value over here would do)
        node.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = 1

        // Add it to the Scene
        addChild(node)
        
        // Create a red square with a volume based physics body that isn't dynamic
        let otherNode = SKSpriteNode(color: .red, size: CGSizeMake(50, 50))
        otherNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSizeMake(50, 50))
        otherNode.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false

        // Set the position to be 100 pts to the right of the yellow square
        otherNode.position = CGPointMake(200, 100)

        // Add it to the Scene
        addChild(otherNode)
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // Moves yellow square to where you tapped on the screen
        guard let finger = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }
        node.run(.move(to: finger, duration: 1))
    }

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        print("did begin contact")
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Game")
            SpriteView(scene: GameScene(), debugOptions: [.showsPhysics, .showsNodeCount])
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`didBegin(contact:)` won't fire if `.isDynamic = false` so delete those lines and add `physicsWorld.gravity = .zero` to keep nodes from falling.

Comment: I don't want the physics simulation to move the nodes, I want them to basically just overlap each other. How can I do this?

Comment: I realised I can probably just set the collision bit mask to 0. Thanks for this

Comment: P.S. You only need to set one of the `contactTestBitMask`s for it to work

Comment: yes you're right. updated answer accordingly

Answer (score -1):

When you're using physics bodies, you should avoid moving nodes using actions. Instead move the bodies by setting forces and/or impulses, with methods like [applyForce(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520430-applyforce) and [applyImpulse(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519900-applyimpulse).

This will allow the physics engine to simulate the physics interactions correctly.

Comment: How would I make the node go toward where I tapped the screen? Wouldn't I need to do some advance physics calculations to determine the friction and stuff? Or is there an easier way to make the node go toward the finger